# Debugging JSF java.lang.ClassCastException in Restore View Phase

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'd like some advice on how I may attempt to debug the cause of a JSF exception and/or know whether anyone has seen this behaviour before. I'll use the following notation to describe the problem:

- 'A' - means viewing page A,
- 'A, CmdLink => B' - means viewing page B after clicking on a `<h:commandLink>` link in page A,
- 'A, URL => B' - means viewing page B by entering its URL in the address bar and pressing enter while viewing page A. (So JSF has still previously generated page A.)

I get the following `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
```

when clicking the link in page B in the following sequence:

- A, CmdLink => B, CmdLink => C

So the error page with the exception is displayed instead of page C. However, the following scenarios do not generate the error:

- A, URL => B, CmdLink => C
- D, CmdLink => B, CmdLink => C

And this sequence does not generate an error the second time, so page C is correctly displayed:

- A, CmdLink => B, CmdLink => ErrorPage (instead of C), URL => B, CmdLink => C

The exception only occurs when page A was the previously viewed page to page B (and page B was not reached by directly entering the URL in the browser's address bar).

Page A is a complex page with multiple drop-down boxes, RichFaces components, an OpenFaces tabSet, multiple datatables, and uses RichFaces AJAX (a4j) whereas page B does not use any of these, only a simple form with command links. Both pages use the same JSF template hierarchy. (Page B is a simple edit page for one of the items listed in a datatable in a tab section on page A.)

The issue is not confined to page B being the page following page A. This sequence also gives the same exception with the error page displayed after clicking on a link in page E:

- A, CmdLink => E, CmdLink => F

I've tried adding a phase listener with the following output produced after clicking on the link in page B:

```
INFO: ++++++ START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1 ++++++
INFO: ++++++ END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1 ++++++
```

I'm using NetBeans 7.2, Glassfish 3.1, RichFaces 4.3.3 Final, OpenFaces 3.0, and JSF 2.1.

Any useful suggestions would be appreciated as to how I may attempt to resolve this problem - thanks.

Comment: *The exception only occurs when page A was the previously viewed page to page B* the only think I can come up is that you're storing an `Object object` (or similar) as request attribute with the same name of another request attribute used in view C. If not in request scope, then probably in session or application scope, but it is the same principle.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this. Most of the backing beans in the project are SessionScoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this problem as there was another link (call it CmdLinkA2) on Page A (in a different tab) which when followed:

- A, CmdLinkA2 => B, CmdLink => C

doesn't cause the above error message, and Page C is displayed correctly. Comparing the different backing bean action methods used for the problematic `<h:commmandLink>` and the working one (CmdLinkA2) on Page A, the `String` returned to the problematic CmdLink was missing `?faces-redirect=true` on the end, i.e. equivalent to:

1) `<h:commandLink value="Next page" action="nextpage.xhtml" />`

instead of:

2) `<h:commandLink value="Next page" action=nextpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />`

where (1) leads to the error message occurring instead of Page C.

However, since Page A does not have any form data to submit, as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242240/), I now understand page-to-page navigation should not be performed using POST at all.

Comment: Actually, after reading this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink "When should I use an <h:outputLink> instead of an <h:commandLink>?"), it's made me realise that I was correct to use `<h:commandLink>` for page navigation as there are actions to be performed by the backing bean before the next page can be displayed, even though there is nothing for Page A to post back to the server.